# How do I create an Azure App Service Managed Certificate when the App Service's inbound IP address is missing?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate

B"H

The key here is that the App Service's inbound IP address is missing.

Everything else works fine. I can actually find the public ip address using nslookup. So even custom domains work fine. I just create an A record pointing to the IP address that I found with nslookup. Even SSL works on subdomains because I have CNAME records pointing to the default domain, and the Managed Certificates work fine with CNAME records.

However the root (apex) domain must use an A record, and being that that IP address doesn't match what is in Azure (blank), the Managed Certificate system rejects it.

To demonstrate in a few images
[image: Blank Incoming IP Address]
You see that where the incoming IP address is usually listed, it's just blank.

Even the error message that Azure gives me is missing information. You can see that there's an unexpected null variable that they're outputting in the error message. Where the IP should be, there's just a blank.
[image: Error message when I try to create an SNI SSL certificate]

That error happens whether I try SNI SSL or IP Based SSL.

Comment: I'm don't have a lot of experience with the finer points of certs, but I thought a cert generally pointed at a name, not the IP address.

Comment: It could be either one. But this is a question about their particular setup. How it works in Azure. Where they require for a root (apex) domain to have the IP that matches the App Service. But that's not possible if the App services doesn't have an IP address in its settings

Comment: Keeping in mind I can't see any images (and they aren't encouraged anyway). What are yout trying to do? Is there an area in this doc that describes what you want to do? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex

Comment: Based on my [domain registrar search/dig](https://in.godaddy.com/whois/results.aspx?domain=chabadofnewpaltz.com) for your chabadofnewpaltz.com, it's hosted on GKG.Net, Inc.

Diginterface for records. 

Ensure both IP SSL and SNI-based bindings are not configured (you'd tried this combination)

Comment: Based on my [domain registrar search/dig](https://in.godaddy.com/whois/results.aspx?domain=chabadofnewpaltz.com) for your chabadofnewpaltz.com, it's hosted on GKG.Net, Inc.

[Digwebinterface](https://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=chabadofnewpaltz.com&type=CNAME&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) for records. 

Ensure both IP SSL and SNI-based bindings are not configured (you'd tried this combination). Side note, App Service managed certificate (ASMC) vs App Service certificate (ASC) - Free ASMC comes with comes with some limitations (outlined in the doc that Nick shared)